# How can I persist ForeignKey fields into database using Django

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, model

I am new to Django I have two models are user and address, here user having two 
foreign key fields are 'localaddress', 'permanentaddress'

Address model:

```
class Address(models.Model):

fulladdress = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
additional_address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
street_address = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
route = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
state = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
pincode = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'address'
```

User model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
   localaddress = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="localaddress", null=True, blank=True)
   permanentaddress = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="permanentaddress", null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
       db_table = 'user'
```

settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'student.User'# changes built-in user model to ours
```

here both localaddress and permanentaddress having same foreign key (Address model only)

Edit form:

forms.py:

```
class LocaladdressForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Address

    fields = ['fulladdress', 'additional_address', 'street_address', 'route', 'city', 'state', 'country', 'pincode']

def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(LocaladdressForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.fulladdress = self.cleaned_data['fulladdress']
        user.additional_address = self.cleaned_data['additional_address']
        user.street_address = self.cleaned_data['street_address']
        user.route = self.cleaned_data['route']
        user.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
        user.state = self.cleaned_data['state']
        user.pincode = self.cleaned_data['pincode']
        user.country = self.cleaned_data['country']

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

views.py:

```
def address_form(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    address = Address()
    form = AddressForm(request.POST, instance=address)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        userid = request.user.id
        User.objects.filter(pk=userid).update(localaddress=address)
        return redirect(reverse('student:view_profile'))
    else:
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'student/addressform.html', args)
else:
    form = AddressForm()
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'student/addressform.html', args)
```

i am using for loop to render form elements, i don't know where i did wrong

addressform.html:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.fulladdress }}
        {{ form.additional_address}}
        {{ form.street_address}}
        {{ form.street_address }}
        {{ form.city }}
        {{ form.state }}
        {{ form.pincode }}
        {{ form.country }}          
</form>
```

Here i need to render one form localaddress and another form permanentaddress foreign key fields to my template. Initially i am trying first form (localaddress) please help me any one.

Thanks in advance ...

Localaddress form screenshot: Here i did it Autocomplete Address Form using google address api reference link here [Autocomplete Address](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

```
I am able to persist address and user object but user object creating new object it is not persisting existing object (means localaddress)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can answer partially about a concept in Django.

Whenever you create a relationship between two Django models you decide which model will be the main model. Over here you have User model and Address model. I am sure in most cases you will agree that User model is the main model and Address will be the sub-model or child model or whatever you call it.

So your `ForeignKey` field should ALWAYS be on the sub-model. So instead of using ForeignKey on User model like you have done you should do something like this:

```
address_type_choices = [
    (1, 'Local'),
    (2, 'Permanent'),
]

class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    type = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=address_type_choices)
    house = model.CharField(max_length=50)
    road = model.CharField(max_length=50)
    area = model.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
```

Please change the structure of your model and edit the question. I am sure that is what others will suggest too.

Remember, main model will not have foreign key field.

**Update:** Changed the model to allow you to maintain both local and permanent address.

Comment: In addition to this good suggestion: you don’t need to add the ForeignKey field to your form because your view should assign the address to the correct user (`request.user`). It would be totally insecure to assign the user based on a `id` submitted via a form.

Comment: @MiniGunnR thank you so much for quick response here my User model is main model and address is sub model , i am trying here both local and permanent address foreign keys are having address fields like (address row i am storing street, city, country, pincode ...). I am not sure like this works are not but how can i maintain both local address and permanent address having all address fields

Comment: How can i maintain User model having local and permanent address foreign keys(these two fields contain all address model fields), here i am trying one to many relationship i am not sure whether one to many or many to many relationship

Comment: @somesh I updated the answer to allow you to maintain both types of address.

Comment: @MiniGunnR Thank you so much i update my post can check once i successfully persist address object but in user table there is no address id , here i created two forms like localaddress form and permanentaddress forms both i am persisting seperately now i persists local address from i am trying here address id to save corresponding user foreign key(localaddress field)

Comment: Sorry I am not understanding very clearly. If you can make the form you want in HTML and upload a screenshot it will be much more clear to me.

Comment: @MiniGunnR I added screenshot can you check above once

Comment: @MiniGunnR i am not posting my entire html file i only posted form fields inside view i created new address form how can i map address id to User model localaddress field( means whenever i persist address object that id should save localaddress field in User model

Comment: @MiniGunnR Finally i got solution according to my answer i change above post also thank you so much for your valuable support ...

Comment: Glad I could help.